# receiving a web page from web server in a c program

Tags: c, buffer

Here is my code to get a web page from a server (actually google.com):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char http[] = "GET / HTTP/1.1\nAccept: */*\nHost: www.google.com\nAccept-Charset: utf-8\nConnection: keep-alive\n\n";
char page[BUFSIZ];

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct addrinfo hint, *res, *res0;

    char *address = "www.google.com";
    char *port = "80";

    int ret, sockfd;

    memset(&hint, '\0', sizeof(struct addrinfo));

    hint.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hint.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
/*  hint.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP; */

    if((ret = getaddrinfo(address, port, &hint, &res0)) < 0)
    {
        perror("getaddrinfo()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for(res = res0; res; res = res->ai_next)
    {
        sockfd = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);

        if(-1 == sockfd)
        {
            perror("socket()");
            continue;
        }

        ret = connect(sockfd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);

        if(-1 == ret)
        {
            perror("connect()");
            sockfd = -1;
            continue;
        }

        break;

    }

    if(-1 == sockfd)
    {
        printf("Can't connect to the server...");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    send(sockfd, http, strlen(http), 0);

    recv(sockfd, page, 1023, 0);

    printf("%s\n", page);

    return 0;
}
```

I've just defined an array of 'BUFSIZ' chars in order to store the web page. The BUFSIZ is actually 1024 character on my operating system and therefor, I can store a web page with 1024 char length. But what if the page was actually larger than 1024? I mean, how can I store a page that is larger than 1024 character? I could define an array of 2048, 4096 or even 10,000 chars, but I think it is not the conventional way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One typical solution is to call `recv(2)` in a loop and keep processing (printing ?) received bytes. That way you can receive pages of any size.

```
ssize_t nread;

while ((nread = recv(sockfd, page, sizeof page, 0)) > 0) {
    /* .... */
}

if (nread < 0)
    perror("recv");
```

Answer (score 1):

What you typically do is store the data in a *dynamic array*, which in C is implemented using [`realloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc) to grow a block of memory.

You usually use a smaller statically allocated array like yours to do repeated reads into, and then once you've gotten a new block of bytes you append it to the dynamic array, growing it if needed.

You're going to have to keep track of the dynamic array's actual length (the number of downloaded characters that have been stored in it) and it's allocated length (the number of bytes *available* to store data in) separately.

Comment: I like your `realloc` idea. How about allocating a small amount of memory, reading into it, calling `realloc` and then passing memory + offset for the next read and so on ? With luck , most of the time `realloc` won't have to actually copy data.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic array is a way to handle your "unknown length" issue, when more bytes need to be downloaded, you can enlarge your array dynamically.

I think you can decode the HTTP response header first, if the header has "Content-Length" field, then you know the length of the HTTP response message(response body contains the requested document). This way you can allocate enough space for the page buffer.